# Show alert with the content of a Database selection

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am very new to JavaScript what is related to it.

I have a set of dynamic rows and corresponding columns to those rows. In one column I have a button. When I click on it, it displays the results of a `select` query in another page based on the **Posted Competence_ID**.

The query works fine and I get correct results when I click on the button. However, what I would like to do now, is to display that message in **an alert** when the button is clicked and stay on the same page rather than opening a new tab..

Here is the relevant HTML code that shows the table I use:

```
echo "<table border='1' id='mycompstable' class='sortablee' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Competence Group</th><th>Competence Class</th><th>Competence Description</th><th>Own Evaluation</th><th>Manager's evaluation from last year</th><th>Target levels</th><th>Gap</th><th>Action</th><th class='unsortable'>Action ready target </th></tr>";

foreach($descs as $compi){  
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$compi['Competence_ID']."</td>";
        echo "<td><p style='text-align: center;'>".$compi['Competence_Group']."</p></td>";
        if(isset($compi['Competence_class'])){echo "<td>".$compi['Competence_class']."</td>";}else echo "<td><p style='text-align: center;'>-</p></td>";
        echo "<td>".$compi['Competence_Description']."</td>";
        echo "<td class='evaluation'>";
            echo "<select class='ownlevelselect' id='ownlevelselect-.".$compi['Competence_ID']."' name='level-".$compi['Competence_ID']."' >";
               if (isset($compi['ownlevel']) && $compi['ownlevel']!= '' && !empty($compi['ownlevel']) && $compi['ownlevel']!= 0) {
                  echo "<option selected value='".$compi['ownlevel']."' selected='selected'>".$compi['ownlevel']."</option>";

                }
                echo "<option value='' >--</option>";
                echo "<option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option>";
            echo "</select>";
            echo $compi['ownlevel'];


            echo '<a test="'.$compi['Competence_ID'].'" onClick="showLevels('.$compi['Competence_ID'].');" target="_blank" href="'.INDEX.'?categ='.$_GET['categ'].'&action='.$_GET['action'].'&subaction=viewlevels'.'&levels='.$compi['Competence_ID'].'">';
            echo '<img class="linkki" src="'.KUVAT.'paivita.gif" alt="'._("tiedot").'" title="'._("Click to view the description of each level?").'"/></a>';
        echo "</td>";
```

Here is the code to retrieve the data:

```
    function fetchlevels($Competence_id){
    $this->query="SELECT * FROM levels WHERE comp_id=".$_REQUEST['levels'];
    $tulos=$this->suoritaKysely();
    return $tulos;
}
```

And here is the page that I want to show in the message:

```
$levels=$this->levels;
$comp=$this->compdesc;
echo "Levels explanation for the competence:".$comp['Competence_Description']."<br>";

echo "Level 1 =  ".$levels[0]['lvl1'];
echo "<br>"."level 2 = ".$levels[0]['lvl2'];
echo "<br>"."level 3 = ".$levels[0]['lvl3'];
echo "<br>"."level 4 = ".$levels[0]['lvl4'];
echo "<br>"."level 5 = ".$levels[0]['lvl5'];
echo "<br><br>";
echo '<input type="button" value="close" window onclick="window.close();">';



?>
```

Any kind of help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Ajax simulation in jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/ncubica/Umxjb/

**HTML**

```
<i style='display:none' id="loadingPopup">Loading</i>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td data-id="td1"> row 1</td>
    </tr>        
   <tr>        
        <td data-id="td2"> row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-id="td3"> row 3</td>
    </tr>        
</table>
```

**javascript**

```
$("table").on("click", function(event){
    var $target = $(event.target); 
    if($target.is("td")){
        var id = $target.attr("data-id");
        makeAjax(id);
    }
});

//simulating ajax

function makeAjax(id){
    //you will have to use ajax an retrieve you json format
    //i will simulate ajax only
    $("#loadingPopup").show();
    var _json = { id : id, value : "some value", description : "some description"};
    setTimeout(function(){response(_json)}, 1000);
}

function response(_json){
    $("#loadingPopup").hide();    
    alert(_json.id + " - " + _json.value);
}
```

**CSS**

```
table{font-family:arial; font-size:12px; width:100%}
table tr td{border-bottom:1px solid #CCC; padding:10px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an example based on the given info!

```
echo '<a onClick="showLevels('.$compi['Competence_ID'].');">';
echo '<img class="linkki" src="'.KUVAT.'paivita.gif" alt="'._("tiedot").'" title="'._("Click to view the description of each level?").'"/></a>';
```

Javascript/jQuery/Ajax

```
function showLevels(comp_id)
    {

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "process_file.php?comp_id="+comp_id,
    success: function (result) {
     alert(result);
    }
    });
  }
```

process_file.php

```
    <?php
    //Your database Config.
    $comp_id=$_REQUEST['comp_id'];
    $this->query="SELECT * FROM levels WHERE comp_id=".$comp_id;
     $tulos=$this->suoritaKysely();
     //Proper Output Actions

    $levels=$this->levels;
    $comp=$this->compdesc;
    echo "Levels explanation for the competence:".$comp['Competence_Description']."<br>";

    echo "Level 1 =  ".$levels[0]['lvl1'];
    echo "<br>"."level 2 = ".$levels[0]['lvl2'];
    echo "<br>"."level 3 = ".$levels[0]['lvl3'];
    echo "<br>"."level 4 = ".$levels[0]['lvl4'];
    echo "<br>"."level 5 = ".$levels[0]['lvl5'];
    echo "<br><br>";

         ?>
```

Comment: unfortunately this did not show anything..
This is the URL I have when image is clicked:
`index.php?categ=hr_menu&action=mycomp&subaction=viewlevels&levels=65`

Comment: I Just tried to show the results in alert with jQuery/Ajax! You've to make sure that you are processing everything good in the example page "process_file.php"!

Comment: As you see, I have that DB retrieval done in a function in a separate class. and those "echos" you see in process.php are results of the query that I want to display..

Comment: No good idea of onClick="showLevels('.$compi['Competence_ID'].'); is better to add <a href='javascript:void(0)' data-id='.$compi['Competence_ID'].'>value!</a> and retrieve the value on $("someselector").on("click",function(event){
  var $target = $(event.target);
  if($target.is("a")){
    //retrieve row clicked
    var idclicked = $target.attr("data-id");
  }
});